# git checkout -b, commit some files, checkout back to original branch complains about overridden changes

Tags: git

This surprises me and I can't think of how it can be possible.

1. `git checkout -b newbranch`.
2. commit some files other than `Foo.java`.
3. `git checkout master` (which was the original branch I was on) gives error:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
>   Foo.java
>   Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
>   
>   But I was already on master.  So I do the usual workflow:

1. `git stash`
2. `git checkout master`

And it auto-merges successfully.  Why did it need to auto-merge at all?  Why did it need to block my `git checkout` going *away* from `master` but not *back to* `master`?  I'm trying to understand the logic for when `git` makes these complaints.

Comment: Did you modify `Foo.java` while on the other branch?

Comment: @larsmans I believe I did not.

Comment: I also sometimes believe I didn't edit a file, but some command I issued did. Maybe your IDE added a newline at the end or something. Do a `git status` and `git diff Foo.java` to be sure.

Comment: I've tested on a new repository, and it's working great.

Answer (score 3):

When you used `git checkout -b` it didn't actually go away, it stayed on the same commit. That's why it allowed you to checkout keeping all the local changes. Going "back" to master changes the commit (and actually modifies the working tree), that's why it would override your changes.